# Download large files using pysftp

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, pysftp

I have a file `>500` MB to download using `sftp` connection, I tried using `pysptp` and getting error `SSHException: Server connection dropped:`

```
import pysftp
import sys
myHostname = "dbfiles.xyz.org"
myUsername = "XXXX"
myPassword = "YYYY"
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword,cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
    localFilePath = 'c:/....'
    remoteFilePath = sftp.listdir('/folder/')
    for filename in remoteFilePath:
        if 'string_to_match' in filename:
            local_path =  localFilePath + filename
            print (filename)
            print (local_path)
            sftp.get("folder/" + filename, local_path)
```

And getting `SSHException: Server connection dropped:  EOF error` after 18MB of file is downloaded. Is there any way I can put limit on amount to data downloaded or can delay this `get` process in order to get full file, i tried several ways but because of large file size, unable to download complete file. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you download a complete file using any SFTP client running on the same machine as your Python code?

Comment: Yes, I can download using filezille

Comment: Can you post a log file both from FileZilla and your Python code?

Comment: @Harry_pb, can you please let know how did you overcome this issue, I am also facing same my file size is more than 1.2 GB and its not downloading more than 18MB

Answer (score 0):

Go to Paramiko library in stfp_file.py and change the MAX_REQUEST_SIZE to 1024. It worked for me. You can find the package here:
*/home//.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_file.py*